# Powershell: how to assign path in the beginning of a script

Tags: powershell

As a beginner: How can I place a path to folder in Powershell script? I would like to hard-code a path to a folder where the rest of the script would do some data munging. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
$path = "C:\Windows"

Get-ChildItem $path
```

This will let you reference path in cmdlet parameters.

As per your comment:

```
Set-Location C:\Windows
```

will change working directory of the script to C:\Windows